# Erro na where com váriavel

Tags: php

```
$inter = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE status = 'ativo' AND fixo != 's' AND comentarios != 's' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
                $i = 1;
                $num = '';
                while($in = $inter->fetch()) {
                    if($i == 1){               
                        $num .= "'".$in['id']."', ";               
                    }elseif($i == 2){               
                        $num .= "'".$in['id']."', ";             
                    }elseif($i == 3){               
                        $num .= "'".$in['id']."', "; 
                    }elseif($i == 4){               
                        $num .= "'".$in['id']."', "; 
                    }elseif($i == 5){               
                        $num .= "'".$in['id']."'"; 
                    }
                $noticias = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE status='ativo' AND cat_id='Notícias' AND fixo != 's' AND comentarios != 's' AND id NOT IN ( $num ) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
                    echo $num;
                $i++;} 
                while ($not = $noticias->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

O erro acontece na where AND id NOT IN ( $num ), pois $num não está funcionando no NOT IN, mas é normal no echo, como resolver?

Comment: E na saída do `echo` há a vírgula no final? Aliás, o que esse `if` deveria fazer? Ele executa o mesmo código, independente de `$i`.

Comment: Acho que o problema é a query está sendo executada dentro do while, na verdade não entendi o motivo de fazer isso tudo.

Comment: O if usei para retirar a última vírgula, estou tentando retirar os valores com id da primeira query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito sem a necessidade do PHP, se for MySQL poderá utilizar simplesmente:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     noticias 
WHERE    status='ativo' 
AND      cat_id='Notícias' 
AND      fixo != 's' 
AND      comentarios != 's' 
AND      id NOT IN 
         ( 
                SELECT id 
                FROM   ( 
                                SELECT   id 
                                FROM     noticias 
                                WHERE    status = 'ativo' 
                                AND      fixo != 's' 
                                AND      comentarios != 's' 
                                ORDER BY id DESC limit 5) x) 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Isso irá fazer com que o `NOT IN` tenha os valores do `id` da subquery.

---

### Explicações:

O `NOT IN` suporta tanto valores diretos como `id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5...)` ou também `id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tabela)`, logo isso irá funcionar:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE alguma_coisa IN (SELECT id FROM tabela_dois);
```

Entretanto o MySQL tem suas limitações e não suporta o uso do `LIMIT` dentro do `IN` (e também `NOT IN`, `ANY`, `SOME`, `ALL`).

Afim de resolver o problema do `LIMIT` criamos uma subquery, assim retornamos para o `IN` os valores previamente filtrados, logo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE alguma_coisa IN (
  SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id FROM tabela_dois ORDER BY id LIMIT 10
  ) as nome_da_subquery
);
```

Como toda subquery precisa de um nome foi acrescentado o `x` no final, aqui utilizei o `as nome_da_subquery`, ele pode ser qualquer valor, ele é somente um nome e é definido por `as nome` ou `nome`.

Comment: E ainda assim acho que se ele explicar o que quer é capaz de uma query simples resolver. Tem tanto problema no código original que eu não saberia como orientar só por comentários.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo, estava tentando há horas...